# multiple select filter data with query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do multiple select filter data based on the source on the ticket using a query in Laravel 8 but when I select the multiple sources the data appears only the first choice from the source I chose to filter

he is my code

my controller

```
public function dashboard_realtime_filter(Request $request){
        $project =  Auth::user()->id_project_sementara;
        $currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
        $source = $request->source;
        $string = implode(', ',$source);

        $served = DB::select(DB::raw(
            "SELECT
                COUNT(update_date) AS update_date
            FROM ticket
            WHERE DATE_PART('DAY',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DATE_PART('DAY',ticket.created_at)
            AND ticket.id_project = '$project'
            AND ticket.source IN ('$string')
            "));
        $serveds = $served[0]->update_date;

        return view('dashboard.dashboard_realtime', [
            'served' => $serveds,
            'master_skill' => Master_skill::where('skill_name', '!=', 'All')->get()
        ]);
    }
```

my filter form

```
<form action="{{ url('../dashboard/realtime/filter') }}" method="GET">
    @csrf
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 d-inline justify-content-end d-flex mt-3 mb-3">
       <div class="dropdown">
         <select id="source" name="source[]" class="form-select show-tick ms select2"
           data-placeholder="Select By Channel" multiple required>
             @foreach ($master_skill as $name )
               <option value='{{$name->skill_name}}'>{{$name->skill_name}}</option>
                 @endforeach
          </select>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Filter</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting proper values in $string as array ?

Comment: @TejasPrajapati yeah

Comment: You can try with this syntax $string = implode("', '", $source) may this help.

Comment: your query can probably be sql injected

Answer (score 0):

if each `$source` is text you need to encapsulate each `$source` into a string as `'$source'`:

```php
public function dashboard_realtime_filter(Request $request){
  $project =  Auth::user()->id_project_sementara;
  $currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
  $source = $request->source;

  $string = array_map(function ($source) { return "'" . $source . "'";}, 
$source);
  $string = implode(', ', $string);

  $served = DB::select(DB::raw(
      "SELECT
         COUNT(update_date) AS update_date
       FROM ticket
         WHERE DATE_PART('DAY',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DATE_PART('DAY',ticket.created_at)
         AND ticket.id_project = '$project'
         AND ticket.source IN ({$string})
      "));
  $serveds = $served[0]->update_date;

  return view('dashboard.dashboard_realtime', [
     'served' => $serveds,
     'master_skill' => Master_skill::where('skill_name', '!=', 'All')->get()
   ]);
}
```

Comment: still filtered data based on the first selected option

Comment: @ryoushii16 replace `DB::select` with `DB::query(DB::raw(...))->dd();` to see the query you are building

Comment: think I see the issue here: `AND ticket.source IN ('$string')`, you should not encapsulate `$string` since this would result in double encapsulation: `AND ticket.source IN (''source1', 'source2'')`. That is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing

`$string = implode(', ',$source);`

with

`$string = implode(',',$source);`

Extra blank space might be causing the problem.

Comment: still filtered data based on the first selected option